# Vue cunstom event with parameter returns undefined

Tags: vue.js, events, vuejs2, emit

I have parent and component in Vue application. Childe componentt needs to emit custom event to the parent and send him some parameter. Child looks like

```
<b-button
    v-if="type === 'removed' && campaign && !campaign.authorized"
    class="is-fullwidth"
    type="is-primary"
    :loading="deleteBtnLoading"
    @click="updateDeleted($event, false)"
    >{{
        click
    }}</b-button
>

updateDeleted(e, save = false) {
    console.log(e);  // This works
    console.log(save);  // This works
    this.$emit('updateDeleted', save);
}
```

The parent component is not able to catch save value. The code looks like

```
<DraftChangedModal
    type="removed"
    :devices="removedModalDevices"
    :campaign="campaign"
    :user="user"
    @updateDeleted="updateDraftDeleted(save)"
/>

async updateDraftDeleted(e, save) {
    console.log(e);  // undefined
    console.log(save);  // undefined
},
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter how function parameters are named in `async updateDraftDeleted(e, save)` function signature. If it was provided with `undefined` arguments when being called, parameters are `undefined`.

`updateDraftDeleted(save)` expression uses `save` property that is local to a component that has this template. If there is no `this.save`, `save` argument is undefined.

There is the [special `$event` variable](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Methods-in-Inline-Handlers) that is available for expressions that are bound to events. This should be done in the parent the same way as in the child:

```
@updateDeleted="updateDraftDeleted($event)"
```

Comment: Yes thats it. @updateDeleted gets the save parameter as $event param. Thanks a lot.